# Opera Mobile and jQuery Mobile Select menus display bug

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, select-menu, opera-mobile

There is a bug in jQuery mobile with Opera Mobile which displays the default select over the custom one from jQuery Mobile, see the screenshot below directly taken from jQuery Mobile's website!

[image: Opera Mobile and jQuery Mobile Select menus display bug]

Here's the code used by jQuery mobile to hide the select:

```
.ui-select .ui-btn select {
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-appearance: button;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 1.5em;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 3em;
    max-height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    -ms-filter: "alpha(opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Is there any way to hide it as it does on the iPhone and Android default browsers?

Answer (score 4):

I've created a separate CSS-file for the Opera and the following class-overriding worked for me:

```
.ui-select .ui-btn select {
  opacity: 0 !important;
}
```

Also, there is needed to remove the `.ui-select-nativeonly` class from the `.ui-select .ui-btn` elements. I've used jQuery for that:

```
$(function() {
  /**
   * Opera selectors drawings
   */
  $('.ui-select .ui-btn').removeClass('ui-select-nativeonly');

});
```